# Обнуление полей ввода

Tags: php, html, laravel

Есть форма для изменения пароля, при нажатии на submit поля ввода становятся пустыми, соответственно валидатор Laravel ругается на их пустоту, помогите решить проблему. Мне не понятно почему форма становится пустой и видимо на сервер отправляется пустота, хотя указал метод и поля ввода правильно. В чём может быть проблема?

```
{{
    Form::model($user, ['class' => 'form-editprofile',
        'method' => 'PUT',
        'route'  => [
            'users.updatepass',
            $user->id,
        ]
    ])
}}
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">{{__('Edit password')}}</h1>
  @if ($errors->count())
      {{-- Перечень ошибок. --}}
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
          {{ Html::ul($errors->all()) }}
      </div>
  @endif
  <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" value="{{ old('password') }}" placeholder="Пароль" required>
  @if ($errors->has('password'))
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
      </span>
  @endif

  <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Подтвердить пароль" required>
  <hr></hr>
  {{
      Form::submit(
          __('Save'),
          [
              'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block',
          ]
      )
  }} {{Form::close()}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Трудно говорить без серверного кода, но предположу что запрос на обработку формы уходит другому методу контроллера. Согласно документации необходимо отправлять на обновления данных `POST` запрос с вызовом в теле формы `@method('PUT')`. В результате мы сообщаем что отправляем именно PUT запрос. Не помню все методы `FORM & HTML` библиотеки, поэтому если метод `Form::modal()` с указанием в качестве параметра `'method' => 'PUT'`, не делает данных операций описанных мною выше, то укажите их в ручную

Comment: Только что проверил, оказалось, что натыкаюсь второй на такую же ошибку, когда в Request'е не видит значения полей формы. Всё почему? Потому что я указал в валидаторе не те имена полей, поэтому он не видит их, следовательно не может считать с них ничего, поэтому и думает что они пустые. Думаю проблему решить можно чётко проверив имена полей, так как валидатор обращается к именам, а не к id элемента на форме.

Comment: И да html не поддерживает метод put, нужно указывать форму с методом post и указать два поля input с указанием маршрута put.